# Geodesics (Local vs Global)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesics

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, and $p,q\in M$ two points. Now, if $M$ is a complete metric space the Hopf–Rinow theorem ensures that there is a geodesic $C\subset M$ joining $p$ and $q$ that minimizes distance.

On the other hand, we always have the notion of geodesic as curve that locally in a neighborhood of a given point minimizes distance.

My question is the following: can the global geodesic $C$ be constructed by "smoothly prolonging" local geodesics? Here with "smoothly prolonging" I mean that we can find local geodesics $C_1,\dots, C_r\subset M$ with $p\in C_1, q\in C_r$ such that their union $C_1\cup C_2\cup\dots\cup C_r = C$ is smooth.

Comment: You need to be more precise about what you mean by "smoothly prolonging", for the question to have a definite answer.

Comment: You are right. I tried to be more precise.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly this is about uniqueness of solutions of ode’s. The answer is yes ( if the metric is sufficiently smooth)

Comment: @ThomasRot I am not even sure if it is about uniqueness; it seems to be about localization. I think the question (which has a positive answer by the way) is essentially: "if $\gamma : [0,1]\to M$ is a length-minimizing geodesic from $\gamma(0)$ to $\gamma(1)$, then for any $0 \leq s < t \leq 1$, is $\gamma|_{[s,t]}$ a length minimizing geodesic between the end-points?" For complete $(M,g)$ this is true.

Comment: Yes, this was precisely my question. Thank you. Is this trivial when $M$ is complete?

Comment: completeness is not even required (slip of hand there when I typed the previous comment). No exactly trivial (since the proof is somewhat tedious), but it is done in most Riemannian geometry textbooks. Essentially if there is a shorter path from $\gamma(s)$ to $\gamma(t)$, you can form a piecewise smooth curve joining $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$ with smaller length. Then you have to either (i) prove length minimizers are automatically $C^\infty$ or (ii) prove that for any $\epsilon$, a piecewise smooth curve can be smoothly approximated by a curve no more than $\epsilon$ longer.

Comment: For (ii) you can work in a small coordinate neighborhood and just "round the corner" on a sufficiently small scale. There's some epsilons and deltas you have to keep track of but the proof is straightforward (if you can do it in Euclidean space, the proof carries over with almost zero changes).

Comment: Careful: if you want $C$ to be a smooth 1-dimensional embedded submanifold, of course you can't ensure that. Look at the geodesics on the generic ellipsoid. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid

Comment: What do you mean by local and global geodesics? In Riemannian geometry there is just one notion, simply a geodesic (a curve of zero acceleration). Are you asking if every geodesic is a finite union of minimizing geodesics? This is of course false.

Comment: My understanding is that curves of zero acceleration are those that minimize distance locally. Now take any two points on M an a geodesic joining them (curve of minimal length among those joining the two points). Can we write M as a fine union of curves of zero acceleration?

Comment: Every minimizing curve will be geodesic, i.e. have zero acceleration, if you parameterize it by it's arc length. This is covered in any Riemannian geometry textbook.